# Group by expression in pig

Tags: apache-pig

Consider I have a dataset with tuples (f1, f2). I want to get my data in two bags: one where fi is null and the other where f1 values are not null. I try:

```
raw = LOAD 'somedata' USING PigStorage() AS (f1:chararray, f2:chararray);
raw_group = GROUP raw BY f1 is null;
raw_count = FOREACH raw_group GENERATE group, COUNT_STAR(raw);
```

I expect to get two groups with keys true and false. When I run it in grunt I get the following:

```
2013-12-26 14:56:10,958 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - 
ERROR 1200: <line 1046, column 25>  Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near 'f1'
```

I can do a workaround:

```
raw_group = GROUP raw BY (f1 is null)?0:1;
```

, but I really like to understand what's going on here, as I just started to learn Pig. According to Pig [documentation](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#GROUP) I can use expressions as a grouping key. Do I miss something here or nulls are treated differently in Pig?

Comment: What version of Pig are you using? Booleans only recently became a full-fledged datatype in Pig. Your workaround seems just fine. And as a note -- in your workaround, you *are* using an expression as a grouping key.

Comment: Version 0.9.2. I believe booleans are supported there? For your note - that's why I am puzzled in the first place. I'd like to understand what's going on as I have a lot of nulls in different parts of my dataset and such workarounds are extra work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boolean datatype was [introduced in Pig 0.10](http://hortonworks.com/blog/new-features-in-apache-pig-0-10/).  The expression `f1 is null` is a boolean, so it can't appear as a field in a relation, which it would do if it were the value of `group`. Prior to Pig 0.10, booleans could only be used in `FILTER` statements or in the ternary operator, as you showed in your workaround.

While I haven't tried this out, presumably if you were to attempt the same thing in Pig 0.10 or later, your original attempt would succeed.